# Python: requests lib post request not sending proper json format data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to connect to a very closed source database system via REST API to pull some data. The API so weird that it just gives you status code 400 & nothing much. No information or error pointing to what is wrong with the provided data. I am calling this API using postman & it is giving me proper response but when I use Python's requests lib to call this API I am getting 400 status (Which means there is something wrong with the provided data with the request).

This is my code.

```
def pull_data():
    url = construct_url(configs.get("get_data_path"))

    payload = json.dumps([
        {
            "SampleInterval": 600000,
            "GetEnum": False,
            "ResampleMethod": "Around",
            "MinimumConfidence": 0,
            "MaxRows": 100,
            "TimeFormat": 6,
            "ReductionData": "avg",
            "TagName": [
                "NC_AI3",
                "NC_AI32"
            ],
            "StartTime": "05/16/2022 08:49:26.000",
            "EndTime": "05/16/2022 13:03:36.000",
            "OutputTimeFormat": 6,
            "EventSequence": 0
        }
    ])
    
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    res = requests.post(url, json=payload, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(configs.get("user"), configs.get("password")), headers=headers)

    
    print("----------", "Status Code", res.status_code, "-------")
```

I think somehow the json data sent via the `request.post` method is not getting recognised  by the API. I think it is something to do with the fact that I am sending list of dict as json error not a usual dict as we do or see everywhere.

Can please someone tell if I am sending the json data correctly or not or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @python_user I had tried that as well but no luck

Comment: `json.dumps` will always produce valid json, so the body you construct using Python must be different (shape and structure) from the one you send via Postman. Another possibility is if the API requires particular headers that you are sending from Postman but not from Python

Comment: "I think it is something to do with the fact that I am sending list of dict as json error not a usual dict as we do or see everywhere" ...have you tried just sending the dict then, instead of wrapped in a list?  Is that the difference in the Postman request?

Comment: @Anentropic I can't send dict directly as that is not the expected structure as per the documentation of the API. About the extra headers except the auth others are auto generated headers in Postman but still I will take a look.

Comment: Just carefully compare the shape of data body sent from Postman vs sent from Python.  It's also possible that individual fields in the dict have values the API doesn't like, e.g.`"StartTime": "05/16/2022 08:49:26.000"` ... check that this is the same date format that you send from Postman

Comment: @Anentropic I just copied that json part from the Postman's code snipped generator tool but still checking it.